# Is there a way to monitor UDP packets being sent to my local Apache server?

Tags: java, apache, sockets, networking, udp

I am trying to send UDP packets from my Android application to my local Apache server. However, I am not sure whether or not the UDP packets are actually getting sent to the Apache server. I checked the access.log file of my Apache server, and only GET requests are shown (from when I tested the server by connecting to it in the browser). If UDP packets are getting sent to the Apache server, would they show up in the access.log file? And if not, how can I check to see if my Apache server is receiving these UDP packets that I am sending it? I am using DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket to send the UDP packets. I am on Windows 10 and the Android application is in Java. Thanks!

Comment: Apache httpd is a _webserver_, e.g. serving http and https, which run on tcp. It's not a general "serve everything" server, unless you enable/write specific modules that explicitly allow other protocols. Why you'd want to do that to a webserver is beyond me, when it's simpler to just write a standalone server

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Apache doesn't use UDP. It does use TCP though.